# Simplest way to increment a date in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime, date-manipulation

Say I have a string coming in, `"2007-02-28"`, what's the simplest code I could write to turn that into `"2007-03-01"`? Right now I'm just using `strtotime()`, then adding `24*60*60`, then using `date()`, but just wondering if there is a cleaner, simpler, or more clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A clean way **is** to use `strtotime()`

```
$date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("2007-02-28"));
echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
```

Will give you the 2007-03-01

Answer (score 36):

It's cleaner and simpler to add 86400. :)

The high-tech way is to do:

```
$date = new DateTime($input_date);
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

but that's really only remotely worthwhile if you're doing, say, a sequence of transformations on the date, rather than just finding tomorrow.

Comment: Stupid CentOS only has PHP 5.1, and DateTime is introduced in 5.2. I guess I finally have to upgrade to an unofficial centos php package then.

Comment: Er, no. Just adding 86400 is false simplicity.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: It is quite easy to understand what 24*60*60 means at a glance. 86400 less so.

Comment: Ah.  I guess I've been doing this too long, then.  86400 is as recognizable to me as 65536.

Comment: @chaos: If your smallest unit of working time is a day, then you can usually get away with adding or substracting units of 86400. If it is smaller, you need to be aware of daylight savings and time zones. In which case, use the built-in functions. They will get it right more often than you will.

Comment: Not all days are 86400 seconds long (leap seconds).

Answer (score 17):

You can do the addition right inside strtotime, e.g.

```
 $today="2007-02-28";
 $nextday=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("$today +1 day"));
```

Comment: Oh, neat.  Didn't know that.  It's almost like good old Date::Manip.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use function mktime(). It is very useful function...

```
$date = "2007-02-28";
list($y,$m,$d)=explode('-',$date);
$date2 = Date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d+1,$y));
```

but I think `strtotime()` is better in that situation...

Comment: nice, I didn't realise that mktime() would increment the month like that when you go over

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way...

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 day"));    //from today
```

OR from specified date...

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 day", strtotime('2007-02-28')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this below especially if you are french

```
$date = date('l j F Y');
#increment the date
$date2 = date('l j F Y', strtotime("+7 day"));
```

to translate in french you can use the setlocale() function or the function  below :

```
function fr_date($date){

    $date = explode(' ', $date);

    $date = str_replace('Monday','Lundi',$date);
    $date = str_replace('Tuesday','Mardi',$date);
    $date = str_replace('Wednesday','Mercredi',$date);
    $date = str_replace('Thursday','Jeudi',$date);
    $date = str_replace('Friday','Vendredi',$date);
    $date = str_replace('Saturday','Samedi',$date);
    $date = str_replace('Sunday','Dimanche',$date);

    $date = str_replace('January','Janvier',$date);
    $date = str_replace('February','Février',$date);
    $date = str_replace('March','Mars',$date);
    $date = str_replace('April','Avril',$date);
    $date = str_replace('May','Mai',$date);
    $date = str_replace('June','Juin',$date);
    $date = str_replace('July','Juillet',$date);
    $date = str_replace('August','Août',$date);
    $date = str_replace('September','Septembre',$date);
    $date = str_replace('October','Octobre',$date);
    $date = str_replace('November','Novembre',$date);
    $date = str_replace('December','Décembre',$date);

    $date = implode(' ',$date);
    return $date;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_date = strtotime("1month", strtotime(date("Y-m-d")));
 $new_date = date("Y-m-d", $your_date++);
```

Comment: /("1month")= will increment by month.
//("1day")= will increment by day.
//(date("Y-m-d"))=start to increment date on you current date.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the explanation of the code, instead of having the explanation in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime()` With date Formate

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2007-02-28' . ' +1 day'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $early_start_date = date2sql($_POST['early_leave_date']);


        $date = new DateTime($early_start_date);
        $date->modify('+1 day');


        $date_a = new DateTime($early_start_date . ' ' . $_POST['start_hr'] . ':' . $_POST['start_mm']);
        $date_b = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $_POST['end_hr'] . ':' . $_POST['end_mm']);

        $interval = date_diff($date_a, $date_b);
```