# PHP- Display days weekly by giving 2 dates

Tags: php

I'd like display dates by week number between giving 2 dates like example below. Is this possible in PHP?

if the dates are 2010-12-01 thru 2010-12-19, it will display it as follows.

```
week-1  
 2010-12-01  
 2010-12-02  
 2010-12-03  
 2010-12-04  
 2010-12-05  
 2010-12-06  
 2010-12-07  
week-2    
 2010-12-08  
 2010-12-09  
 2010-12-10  
 2010-12-11  
 2010-12-12  
 2010-12-13  
 2010-12-14  
week-3  
 2010-12-15  
 2010-12-16  
 2010-12-17  
 2010-12-18  
 2010-12-19  
and so on...
```

I use mysql. It has startdate end enddate fields.
thank you in advance.

I can get how many weeks in those giving 2 dates and display them using a

```
datediff('ww', '2010-12-01', '2010-12-19', false); I found on the internet.
```

And I can display dates between two dates as follows. But I am having trouble grouping them by week.

```
$sdate = "2010-12-01";
$edate = "2010-12-19";

$days = getDaysInBetween($sdate, $edate);
foreach ($days as $val)  
{  
echo $val;  
} 

function getDaysInBetween($start, $end) {   
// Vars   
$day = 86400; // Day in seconds   
$format = 'Y-m-d'; // Output format (see PHP date funciton)   
$sTime = strtotime($start); // Start as time   
$eTime = strtotime($end); // End as time   
$numDays = round(($eTime - $sTime) / $day) + 1;   
$days = array();   

// Get days   
for ($d = 0; $d < $numDays; $d++) {   
$days[] = date($format, ($sTime + ($d * $day)));   
}   

// Return days   
return $days;   
}
```

Comment: are you using mysql to get these dates?

Comment: are the dates sorted? in an array? more info please.

Comment: I think he wants to display *every* day in a certain range. Grouped by week.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.No, they are not sorted. Mysql has 2 date fields start and enddate.

Comment: Yes, Marnix you are right. Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try? Did it work? Or you just want us to code the script for you?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer.

```
$current_date = strtotime('2010-12-01');
$end_date = strtotime('2010-12-19');
$day_count = 0;
$current_week = null;
do {
    if ((int)($day_count / 7) + 1 != $current_week) {
        $current_week = (int)($day_count / 7) + 1;
        echo 'week-'.$current_week.'<br />';
    }
    echo date('Y-m-d', $current_date).'<br />';
    $current_date = strtotime('+1 day', $current_date);
    $day_count ++;
} while ($current_date <= $end_date);
```

Comment: Thank you dqhendricks for your time and effort. This works great too.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need this: [Simplest way to increment a date in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660501/simplest-way-to-increment-a-date-in-php). Write a forloop and increment the day every time. You will also need the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and functions as [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Indeed asking for `date('W', yourDateHere)` is a nice idea.

You will get something like this (pseudocode)

```
$startDate;
$endDate;

$nrOfDays = dateDiffInDays($endDate, $startDate);
$currentWeek = date('W',$startDate);
for($i = 0; $i < $nrOfDays; $i++)
{
    $newDay = date('+$i day', $startDate); // get the incremented day
    $newWeek = date('W', $newDay); // get the week of the new day

    if($newWeek != $currentWeek) // check if we must print the new week, or if we are still in the current
    print $newWeek;

    print $newDay; // print the day
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: he is asking for week 1 to start in december. your method will not work.

Comment: @dqhendricks: Even easier then: just hold an extra index $j with the weeknumber in it, starting at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Tools sufficient to do the job:

- [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)('2010-11-23') - to get a timestamp from a date
- [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)('+1 day', $someTimestamp) - to get the next day
- [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)('W', $someTimestamp) - to get the week number (if you want to group by ISO week number)
- [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)($orderedListOfSuccessiveDates, 7) - to split in groups of seven days (if you don't want to group by ISO week number)

**Warning:** Never, ever increment days by adding 86400 to the timestamp! That is the easiest way to break everything when Daylight Saving comes along. Either use the `strtotime` function or the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: he is asking for week 1 to start in december. your method will not work.

Comment: Oh... I assumed it was a coincidence and December 1st 2010 was on a Monday. I added `array_chunk` if we just wants groups of 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Although this is with weeks starting on sundays (just change it to monday if need be). And it doesnt work if the dates arent in the same year. But it should be pretty easy to fix that. If not_same_year then ...

```
$start_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 01, 2010);
$start_date_week_number = (int) date("W", $start_date);
$end_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 19, 2010);
$end_date_week_number = (int) date("W", $end_date);
$n = $start_date_week_number;
$w = 1;
$date = $start_date;

while($n <= $end_date_week_number) {
    echo("<strong>Week " . $w . "</strong><br />");
    $s = 0;
    $e = 6;
    if($n == $start_date_week_number) $s = (int) date("w", $start_date);
    elseif($n == $end_date_week_number) $e = (int) date("w", $end_date);
    while($s <= $e) {
        echo(date("j-m-y", $date) . "<br />");
        $c_date = getdate($date);
        $date = mktime($c_date['hours'], $c_date['minutes'], $c_date['seconds'], $c_date['mon'], $c_date['mday'] + 1, $c_date['year']);
        $s++;
    }
    $n++; $w++;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/vCr1xMLM)

Edit: just fixed it when I realized you wanted to count the weeks (not get the actual week number)...

Answer (score 1):

```
    $startDate = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
    $endDate = new DateTime('2010-01-14');
    $weeksDays = getWeeksDaysBetween($startDate, $endDate);

    foreach($weeksDays as $week => $days)
    {
      echo "Week $week<ul>";
      foreach($days as $day){
        echo "<li>$day</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>";
    }

  function getWeeksDaysBetween($startDate, $endDate)
  {
    $weeksDays = array();   
    $dateDiff = $endDate->diff($startDate);
    $fullDays = $dateDiff->d;
    $numWeeks = floor($fullDays / 7) + 1;
    $weeksDays[1][] = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $fullDays; $i++)
    {
      $weekNum = floor($i / 7) + 1;
      $dateInterval  = DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 day");
      $weeksDays[$weekNum][] = $startDate->add($dateInterval)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    return $weeksDays;
  }
```

Comment: I wish I could use new PHP's DateTime class. But My PHP does not have it yet. Hopefully in the future :)