# increment the date

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to increment a date in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660501/simplest-way-to-increment-a-date-in-php)

I am very new to php. I have the current date and I want to increment the date day by day. I don't have any end condition. I want to increment the date day by day for 4 years or so. There should not be a ending for that.
I don't have any other data's like end date, start date. I want to increment the current date one by one using any loop. If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: please use the search function before littering StackOverflow with superfluous duplicates. How to increment dates has been asked a hundred times before and we do not want any more of these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
while (your condition here)
{
   echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $i++ . ' day'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there are many ways to add a day to the current date. The other answers are simpler and quite valid, but the object oriented way is to use [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

It may seem daunting at first glance, but the benefit I’ve found is that [DateTime, DateInterval, and DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) make the quirkiness of timezones and intervals much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

A day is 86400 seconds, so you can simply take the current `time()` and do `+86400`.

```
echo 'Tomorrow it\'s '.date('d-m-Y', time()+86400);
```

Comment: until you hit DST and all of a sudden tomorrow is still today

Comment: That's why you should always try to use noon :-) You make a good point though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `strtotime` for that, like this:

```
for ($i= 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $date = strtotime("+$i day", strtotime("2011-12-01"));
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
}
```

Comment: thank u very much.Its very good idea.very help full to beginer.

Answer (score 0):

Try mktime(). Refer below example for Current Date after 4 years.

```
   echo date('m-d-Y',  mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')+4));
```

more details about mktime() is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php