# PHP date increase

Tags: php, date

I've written a piece of code which converts a date to the specific format and increases it by 1 day.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$mehdate = "2011-11-25";
$mehdate = date ('d m Y', strtotime ('+1 day', strtotime($mehdate)));
echo $mehdate, "\n";
?>
```

But then I have to increase **$mehdate** by 1 day one more time.
And I cannot understand how to do that. I already tried

```
$mehdate = date ('d m Y', strtotime ("+1 day", $mehdate));
```

and

```
$mehdate = date ('d m Y', strtotime ('+1 day', strtotime($mehdate)));
```

again but it won't work because

```
strtotime($mehdate)
```

returns FALSE.
So, how can I increase the $mehdate which was already formatted?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660501/simplest-way-to-increment-a-date-in-php

Comment: I found that if I change 'd m Y' to 'd-m-Y' the code will work fine. But I have to display date as 'd m Y' formatted. And actually I want to find a way to convert $mehdate to 'd-m-Y' after the first block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue can easily be resolved if you use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)  class.

Try this:

```
$mehdate = new DateTime('2011-11-25');

$mehdate->modify('+1 day');
echo $mehdate->format('d m Y')."\n";  // Gives 26 11 2011

$mehdate->modify('+1 day');
echo $mehdate->format('d m Y');       // Gives 27 11 2011
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$mehdate = "2011-11-25";
$mehdate = strtotime ('+1 day', strtotime($mehdate));
$mehdate = date ('d m Y', $mehdate);
echo $mehdate, "\n";
```

Result

```
26 11 2011
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! But what should I do to increase $mehdate one more time?

Comment: If the answer solve you problem, choose it as correct answer, so that others can get benefit. there are several ways to solve your questions. however i just help to find problem in your code so that you can continue with what you doing. hope helps

Comment: one more time? then follow @Object Manipulator approach. thats better

Answer (score 0):

For all newbies like me there is a simple advice: don't use **'d m Y'** format, you'd better operate with **'d-m-Y'**.

Or you have to use **DateTime** class, as Object Manipulator advised.