# How to increase a javascript date variable by one day?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a variable with the current date that has been imported from PHP. "5122016". On the click of a button I need this variable to increase (5132016, 5142016, 5162016) etc and eventually the month and year change with it too. How can I do this? Thank you!

```
<?php
$dateName = date("mdY");
?>

<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#day-right", function(event) {
        var Date = <?php echo $dateName ?>;
        //var Date increases by one day
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this has a javascript tag, it seems to be a PHP question. For incrementing dates in javascript, this is a duplicate of [*Incrementing a date in JavaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript). For PHP it's probably a duplicate of [*Simplest way to increment a date in PHP?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660501/simplest-way-to-increment-a-date-in-php).

Comment: Don't use `Date` as your var name, [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is already a built-in object in JS. JS variable names are case-sensitive, so you could use `date` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> **you can use the follow to add n days:**

```
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + n);
// to add just one day
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $date = date("mdY", strtotime("+1 day")); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this one day added to the current date

```
$dateName  = date("m-d-Y", time() + 86400);
```