# How can I increment a date by one day in Php?

Tags: php

I am using this this syntax to increase one day above but when i put this format it still give me wrong date like this. '01/01/1970'
But I want format and date like this  '25/08/2016'.

```
$today = '24/08/2016';
$nextday = strftime("%d/%m/%Y", strtotime("$today +1 day"));
```

so please help me how can i do this.advance thanx.

Comment: https://eval.in/627939

Comment: Or https://eval.in/627941

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to increment a date in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660501/simplest-way-to-increment-a-date-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$your_date = strtotime("1 day", strtotime("2016-08-24"));
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", $your_date);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use DateTime:

```
$today      = '24/08/2016';    
$nextDay    = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $today)
                ->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))
                ->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 3):

It's important to note the different interpretation of `-` and `/` in the date. If you use a `-` php will determine it to be `DD-MM`, if you use a `/` php will determine it to be `MM-DD`.
So you need to use `-` instead of `/`

```
<?php

$today = '24-08-2016';
echo $nextday = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("$today +1 day"));

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

See below perfect working code

```
<?php
    echo $startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo "<br/>";
    echo $nextDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$startDate +1 day"));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the / with -

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a **slash (/)**, then the American **m/d/y** is assumed; whereas if the separator is a **dash (-) or a dot (.)**, then the European** **d-m-y** format is assumed**.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Try this:

```
$today = '24/08/2016';
$today = str_replace('/', '-', $today);
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today));
$nextday = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($today. "+1 day")); // Output: 25/08/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
<?php
  $today = '24/08/2016';
  $today = explode('/',$today);
  $nextday = date('d/m/Y',mktime(0,0,0,$today[1],$today[0]+1,$today[2])));
?>
```